# Apache add a VirtualHost at an IP address /subdirectroy

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2, virtualhost

Im trying to configure a VirtualHost so that I can go to 192.168.1.179/MYSITE.

When I use this code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName http://192.168.1.179.com
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/apache22/data/PI_Admin
        <Directory /usr/local/www/apache22/data/PI_Admin>
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        RailsBaseURI /pi_admin
    <Directory /usr/local/www/apache22/data/PI_Admin/pi_admin>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

It replaces the entire up with my document root. What id like to do is 192.168.1.179/pi_admin, but that doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration means you have a DNS **192.168.1.179.com** with **/usr/local/www/apache22/data/PI_Admin** being the '/' url for this website.

Don't use named base virtualhosts if you use [IP based ones](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html), maybe simply use the default virtualhost (will be used if no names used in your HTTP requests match any named base virtualhost).

Comment: So youre saying just remove the line servername...?

Comment: No I mean check where is your default VH and add this to it, quite sure you already have one.

Comment: @Oh interesting.. ill give that a shot and let you know.. thanks